# How can I package python source code?

Tags: python

For example, I have a lots of .py file, which can say it is my own library, install of zip all to share my friends, can I have something like .jar in java to package all the classes in a one single file for sharing? Thanks.

Comment: Python eggs are the equivalent of jar files, but I've no idea how they fit with iphone python. I also removed the obj-c tag and replaced it with python.

Comment: Try to read this http://packages.python.org/distribute/index.html and http://diveintopython3.ep.io/packaging.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html , it will walk you through the process. You don't need the uploading part, unless you want to share it on PyPi, but remaining guide should be helpful.